# Magento 2 Installation: getting stuck without error at "Installing user configuration."

Tags: magento2, installation, magento2-dev-beta

I have installed Composer and followed the steps to install Magento2. It will be stuck at 93%. It isn't giving any proper error...

Please check the image:

[image]

Also, it will display in configuration, as below image.

[image]

We got an error in:

> "Installing user configuration."

Is someone facing same issue? If so, how did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just put this code in your `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value  xdebug.max_nesting_level 500
</IfModule>
```

This is known issue with xdebug
[Issue with xdebug](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/tshoot_install-issues.html)

Further you can check here https://blog.amasty.com/magento-2-installation-guide/

Comment: Grt Its Working.

Comment: hi I got Success Page But getting this Message `An error has happened during application run. See debug log for details.`

Comment: Have your installation working properly?

Comment: yes I checked log Its cookie Problem in log

Comment: hey I have some problem I have clone the repo but `magento2\pub\static` whole folders are missing

Answer (score 8):

Following Solution work for me.

In php.ini put following setting

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200;
```

Or If it not work then you can put the following code in top of setup/index.php

```
ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 200)
```

Comment: Ok grate I will check this one also

Comment: Try it .. this solution is also available on https://gist.github.com/wsakaren/a1488ebfd2a75317e94e  I don't know why i am receiving minus points

Comment: i give u +1 vote

Comment: @Frontmage probably because your answer was published two days after the accepted answer with the same solution.

Comment: @ADM Yes i know it is same answer but different way. Because i have solved with this way. We can list out multiple solution to same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the '**vendor**' directory permission to 0777. I got same error and resolved after updating permission...